# dropzone.js is giving error "Invalid dropzone element" on page without a dropzone

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone js and it's working great on pages that I require a dropzone. On any other page though it's giving me a `"Invalid dropzone element"` error message and causing issues with my other javascript.

I have a custom JS file (which loads immediately after the dropzone.js file) and at the very top of the file I have the following line of code:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
```

This should stop it from looking at any page where I'm not enabling it programatically. The error only goes away on pages where there is a valid dropzone.

I also set the following code on line 1470 on dropzone.js to try and enable it there too:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: You can check if the element is there, before you init dropzone. With jQuery you can try something like this: `if ($('#dropzoneDiv').length) { initDropZoneHere }`

Comment: @Philip Where would I put this code?

Comment: Do you use jQuery or pure JS? The idea is that you can check if the div exists before you init Dropzone.

Comment: @Philip I'm using jQuery but would I put this code as a wrapper in the dropzone.js file?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

With pure JS you can try this:

```
if (document.getElementById('DropzoneElementId')) {
  var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#DropzoneElementId", { url: "/file/post"});
  // other code here
}
```

or if you use jQuery:

```
if ($('#DropzoneElementId').length) {
  $("div#DropzoneElementId").dropzone({ url: "/file/post" });
  // other code here
}
```

Comment: This worked. I added it to both files and now I'm good to go. Thanks.

Comment: One thing more keep  in mind you may not use as form with in a form example below:

// Dropzone will not work 

<form action="/post/update" method="post" >
....
<form action="{{ route('upload-files') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="image-upload"  style="height: 500px; background-color: #9ABCEA;">
            @csrf
            <div>
                <h4>Upload Multiple Image By Click On Box</h4>
            </div>
        </form>
</form>

 you will find error in browser console

uncaught Error: Invalid dropzone element.

Answer (score 3):

Long time ago but: Put the script after your Form Element and the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, checking if the target element exists is NOT a requirement.

```
$(".my_element").dropzone(dropzone_options);
```