# how to get dropzone drag n drop working on mac

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, dropzone.js, dropzone

i have implemented a drag n drop form using the drop zone framework

During my testing on this drag n drop from i noticed it worked well on windows system using chrome

but when i tested on my mac using safari browser, the file got dragged but the file was never uploaded to my documents directory.

i am uploading my files on click of a submit button using jquery.

Below is my implementation

**JQUERY**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.1/dropzone.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.1/dropzone-amd-module.js"></script>
<script>
//Disabling autoDiscover
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

$(function() {
    //Dropzone class
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone(".dropzone", {
        url: "upload.php",
        paramName: "file",
        maxFilesize: 20,
        maxFiles: 10,
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        acceptedFiles: ".jpg,.JPG.jpeg,.JPEG,.PNG,.png,.gif",
        autoProcessQueue: false
    });

    $('#startUpload').click(function(){           
        myDropzone.processQueue();
    });
});
</script>
```

**HTML DIV N CSS**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="drop.css">



      <div class="dropzone"></div>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
include_once("data.php");

if(!empty($_FILES)){
$upload_dir = "files/";
$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];


 $newfilename = (rand(100000,1000000000)).$row_ux['Username'];
  $ext = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  $dot = '.';

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'files/'.$newfilename.$dot.$ext)){
  $er = $last_id - 1;
//insert file information into db table

$mysql_insert = "INSERT INTO documents (`file`,adsid)VALUES('".'files/'.$newfilename.$dot.$ext."','".$er."')";

mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_insert) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));

}
}

?>
```

Please what could be the issue with upload on a mac system using dropzone? anynone encountered this?

Comment: any console log errors?

Comment: invalid dropzone element

Comment: invalid dropzpone element @tuckbloor

Comment: does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27870237/dropzone-js-is-giving-error-invalid-dropzone-element-on-page-without-a-dropzon

Comment: i actually av tried that, but to no avail, infact when i used that the upload stopped workin on windows chrome, so mayb i did not implement properly, can you please adjust my code and repost with wat needs to be corrected @tuckbloor

Comment: give me an hour, need fix a few things first myself

Comment: siure thanks @tuckbloor

Comment: do you have this working now?

Comment: onclick and on submit it does nt work @tuckbloor  on mac system